# Show Date outside of defined MinDate MaxDate restrictions

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have googled and tried to find out, but was unable to get a solution on this problem. On page load I am Restricting `datePicker` with following min and max values:

```
$("#<%=txtboxDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({ 
minDate: new Date(2017, 2, 21),
 maxDate: new Date(2023, 07, 11) });
```

But I also have data before `2017-2-21` <-(format of date given is yyyy-mm-dd)
Such as `datePicker` takes this format `mm/dd/yy`. So the date it receives is '2/1/2017'. It is out of `minDate` restriction.

How can I show these kind of dates or just this date `2/1/2017` on `datePicker` calender with same defined restrictions above jquery?

Comment: A date picker is for setting a new date value ... just render the value of the given formatted however you want without the picker. or you can do something like <input type="date" readonly /> in markup

Comment: i don't want to readonly the input field. I want to make the calendar readonly
the calendar right now is like:  dates can be selected, months and years change be changed by using  'next, previous' arrow symbols.  <- i want it viewable with all of these options disabled.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by show these kinds of date. They should appear yet not be selectable in your calendar. You could also make use of `beforeShowDay` function to iterate the days and add classes or perform other such activities.

Comment: @Twisty i mean that after putting the minDate and maxDate restriction, the calendar won't show this date `2/1/2017`  on the calender when it is written down on the textbox. I just want the calendar to also show it..

--second point-- and yeah should appear yet not be selectable <-let's let go of this point for now. just make the date appear on the calendar with those same mindate, maxdate in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<input id="dp" />

var d = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", "12/21/2017");
$('#dp').datepicker({

    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        return [date >= d, ''];
    }
});
$('#dp').datepicker("setDate", "12/10/2017");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant.
The whole point of the restrictions applied with minimal and Max is to control the range of possible dates.

Either update the value to your min date or change min to the date you have

Answer (score 0):

Set the date in the input field before you initialize the date picker ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anshikakaythwas/4rzet8e9/)). 
This will solve your purpose, I suppose.

HTML:

```
Date Picker on input field: <input type="text" id="date1" name="date1"/> <br/>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#thedate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    minDate: new Date(2017, 12, 21),
    maxDate: new Date(2017, 12, 28)
  });

});
```