# Jquery DatePicker - Show the date outside of the minDate - in the Input Box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am having a jquery datepicker which shows the day the task has been created and the day till which the task is available - `Period From` and `Period To`.

The problem is when I go to modify the task - The `Period From` doesn't show anything cause the minDate is always set as `Today`. I just want a way to show the `Period From` date which has been saved already.
The HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
<div class="form-group">
<label>
Period From
<span class="star">*</span>
</label>
<input [disabled]="isValidForm()" #periodFromMonth type="text" value="{{ task.periodFrom }}"
class="form-control datepicker1" name="periodFromMonth" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select Date"/>
</div>
</div>
```

The TypeScript(TS) code:

```
$('.datepicker1').datetimepicker({
                minDate: moment(this.MinDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY').millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0),
                maxDate: moment(this.MaxDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY').millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0),
                
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                icons: {
                    time: 'fa fa-clock-o',
                    date: 'fa fa-calendar',
                    up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
                    down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
                    previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
                    next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
                    today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
                    clear: 'fa fa-trash',
                    close: 'fa fa-remove'
                }
            });
```

It's fine if I don't get to select it. I just want to show the date because in modify the date cannot be changed/modified. Just to show the date in the input box.

I tried following this thread but it is not working at all for my case : [Show Date outside of defined MinDate MaxDate restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432781/show-date-outside-of-defined-mindate-maxdate-restrictions)

Thanks in advance.
Let me know if anything more I need to provide.

Comment: it always trigger me somewhat when i see someone using custom date pickers instead of pure vanilla `input[type=date][min][max]` instead...

Comment: @Endless I don't know my way around it either but it's also not something which I can change just because I want to. I am stuck at this point.